# Check if setup already exists for a Moq mock property?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I'm creating a private method in my unit test class that returns an object with mock dependencies, and I might provide some of those dependencies to the method, or I might not.

Consider the following method under test:

```
public IEnumerable<ServiceObject> GetSomeData(string query)
{
    if (_currentEnvironment.Feeling == Feeling.Cooperative)
    {
        _dataGetter.GetData(query);
    }
}
```

And a method to create an object with appropriately-setup mocks in my test class:

```
private DataService GetTestDataService(Mock<ExecutionEnvironment> mockEnvironment = null, 
Mock<IDataGetter> mockDataGetter = null)
{
    if (mockEnvironment == null)
    {
        mockEnvironment = new Mock<ExecutionEnvironment>();
    }
    if (mockDataGetter == null)
    {
         mockDataGetter = new Mock<IDataGetter>();
    }
    return new DataService(mockEnvironment.Object, mockDataGetter.Object);
}
```

I get in a bind when I need to setup the `ExecutionEnvironment` mock in my tests that need to step into the area where the `GetData` method is called. I need to have every one of those tests set it up to be feeling cooperative. If clauses are added to the "feeling cooperative" conditional, all of the tests will break until I change the setup in every test. I could create a separate method like `CreateDefaultCurrentEnvironmentMock()` that does some default setups, so my tests call that, then override the setups where they need to. However, what I'd *like* to have is all the logic in the same method, which can be accomplished by checking if a setup on the mock already exists, and do a setup if it hasn't been set up yet. Is this possible?

Comment: This sounds more like a test-framework problem then a Moq problem. Could you just have a table of ready-made Mocks to bring in when appropriate? If you are reusing the same object and can't tell the state of your object in your test - that is a design problem.

Comment: @Ryan Bennett Well, the table solution would essentially be the same as the solution I'd proposed where I have a method that creates the mock that my tests call, and then I redefine the setups on the mock. That would work but it would be easier if instead of having to call a method to get the mock, edit it as needed, and then pass it to the other method to get my object under test, I have the latter method be able to inspect the mock that's passed in to it and see if a setup's been defined on it, and if it hasn't, create the default setup. It's a matter of what order the calls have to be in.